# How to query specific columns from an association using sqlalchemy and asyncio?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, python-asyncio

I have the following class:

```
class UsersService:
    db: AsyncSession

    def __init__(self, db: AsyncSession):
        self.db = db

    async def get_user_with_account(self, id) -> Optional[models.User]:
        stmt = (
            select(models.User)
            .options(joinedload(models.User.account).selectinload(models.Account.domains))
            .where(models.User.id == id)
        )
        result = await self.db.execute(stmt)
        return result.scalar_one_or_none()
```

This works well, but I want to select only specific columns from `Account.domains`. I have tried `load_only` but I get the greenlet error due to using asyncio: `greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?`
There is another potential approach of using a subquery. However, I would like to repeat this pattern in many queries, and writing a subquery each time seems like an over-complicated approach.